# Insert array into MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following array I want to store in my database...

```
$insData = array(
    'uid' => $fbme['id'],
    'first_name' => $fbme['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $fbme['last_name'],
    'email' => isset($fbme['email']) ? $fbme['email'] : '',
    'link' => $fbme['link'],
    'affiliations' => $networks,
    'birthday' => $info[0]['birthday_date'],
    'current_location' => isset($fbme['location']['name']) ? $fbme['location']['name'] : '',
    'education_history' => $education,
    'work' => $workInfo,
    'hometown_location' => isset($fbme['hometown']['name']) ? $fbme['hometown']['name'] : '',
    'interests' => $info[0]['interests'],
    'locale' => $info[0]['locale'],
    'movies' => $movies,
    'music' => $music,
    'political' => $info[0]['political'],
    'relationship_status' => $info[0]['relationship_status'],
    'sex' =>  isset($fbme['gender']) ? $fbme['gender'] : '',
    'tv' => $television,
    'status' => '0',
    'created' => $now,
    'updated' => $now,
);
```

I've tried searching google on how to do this and all I can find is information stating my array needs to be split, before inserting into the table. Is this correct? Sorry for the naivity, very new to php.

Comment: Your first step is probably to define your table(s) structure; you can do this very easily in phpMyAdmin. Then do some research around inserting into tables - a web search on "PHP PDO insert example" should bring back hundreds of results. Finally give that a go, paste it into your question, and someone will offer pointers!

Comment: "my array needs to be split before inserting into the table" - that depends. Does your array above contain several tables/rows worth of information? If yes to the second, yes to the first.

Comment: Does a table/tables match the exact schema?

Comment: "my array needs to be split before inserting into the table" - As mentioned, it depends on what you want to achieve. You can insert into the database without splitting though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18655812/5808894 is much better answer.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

**You can not insert an array directly to *MySQL* as *MySQL* doesn't understand *PHP* data types.** *MySQL* only understands *SQL*. So to insert an array into a MySQL database you have to convert it to a SQL statement. This can be done manually or by a library. The output should be an `INSERT` statement.

> **Update for PHP7**
>
> Since PHP 5.5 `mysql_real_escape_string` has been deprecated and as of PHP7 it has been **removed**. See: [php.net's documentation on the new procedure.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

---

**Original answer:**

Here is a standard MySQL insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ....) VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE2..)
```

If you *have a table with name `fbdata` with the columns which are presented in the keys of your array* you can insert with this small snippet. Here is how your array is converted to this statement.

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($insData));
$link = mysqli_connect($url, $user, $pass,$db);
$escaped_values = array_map(array($link, 'real_escape_string'), array_values($insData));

$values  = implode("', '", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `fbdata`($columns) VALUES ('$values')";
```

Comment: Note that **escaping** your values is a very important step. It prevents [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Also note that you may have to add single quotes in the `$values` string for it to work correctly. `$values  = implode("', '", $escaped_values); $sql = "INSERT INTO fbdata ($columns) VALUES ('$values')";`

Comment: If you have some data that's just a single item, e.g. name, and then other data that comes as an array that you want to split up into columns e.g. favourite movies, can you do this (where columns/values are built according to the example in this answer:
INSERT INTO `table`(name, $columns) VALUES ('my name', $values)

Comment: A Fully Working php code of this would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string`, rather you should use  `mysqli_real_escape_string` !!!

Comment: @mintedsky to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` you need to pass the mysqli link to it as well. Of course you should use mysqli or even PDO, but for this sample in this structure...
`mysql_real_escape_string` is ok :) For those who want to know: [see how to use `array_map` with mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35884253/1906168)

Answer (score 28):

There are a number of different ways... I will give you an example of one using prepared statements:

```
$prep = array();
foreach($insData as $k => $v ) {
    $prep[':'.$k] = $v;
}
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table ( " . implode(', ',array_keys($insData)) . ") VALUES (" . implode(', ',array_keys($prep)) . ")");
$res = $sth->execute($prep);
```

I'm cheating here and assuming the keys in your first array are the column names in the SQL table. I'm also assuming you have PDO available. More can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Just for others who may look at this code. It took me a couple tries before I figured out that you have an extra `>` directly after `$prep[':'.$k] =`. If you remove the greater than sign, your code works.

Comment: i dont got it why you add ` : ` before key?

Comment: @rlemon Your code won't do the expected work, until You change the `array_keys($prep)` inside the `VALUES` into `array_values($prep)`. With Your current Code, You'll write the keys as values too.

Comment: @Unkn0wn0x You obvisously don't understand the code. rlemon is using prepared statements. At first he adds `:` to each key in `$prep`. That makes the keys valid placeholder in prepared statements. Secondly, he adds them in with `array_keys($prep)` and uses them with the `$sth->execute($prep)` statement.

Comment: @levye he used : because he know indexes , for example 

<code>
$DB->query("INSERT INTO fruit(id,name,color) VALUES(?,?,?)", array(null,"mango","yellow"));//Parameters must be ordered
$DB->query("INSERT INTO fruit(id,name,color) VALUES(:id,:name,:color)", array("color"=>"yellow","name"=>"mango","id"=>null));//Parameters order free
</code>

Answer (score 7):

Here is my full solution to this based on the accepted answer.
Usage example:

```
include("./assets/php/db.php");
$data = array('field1' => 'data1', 'field2'=> 'data2');
insertArr("databaseName.tableName", $data);
```

### db.php

```
<?PHP
/**
 * Class to initiate a new MySQL connection based on $dbInfo settings found in dbSettings.php
 *
 * @example
 *    $db = new database(); // Initiate a new database connection
 *    mysql_close($db->get_link());
 */
class database{
    protected $databaseLink;
    function __construct(){
        include "dbSettings.php";
        $this->database = $dbInfo['host'];
        $this->mysql_user = $dbInfo['user'];
        $this->mysql_pass = $dbInfo['pass'];
        $this->openConnection();
        return $this->get_link();
    }
    function openConnection(){
    $this->databaseLink = mysql_connect($this->database, $this->mysql_user, $this->mysql_pass);
    }

    function get_link(){
    return $this->databaseLink;
    }
}

/**
 * Insert an associative array into a MySQL database
 *
 * @example
 *    $data = array('field1' => 'data1', 'field2'=> 'data2');
 *    insertArr("databaseName.tableName", $data);
 */
function insertArr($tableName, $insData){
    $db = new database();
    $columns = implode(", ",array_keys($insData));
    $escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($insData));
    foreach ($escaped_values as $idx=>$data) $escaped_values[$idx] = "'".$data."'";
    $values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
    $query = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close($db->get_link());
}
?>
```

### dbSettings.php

```
<?PHP
$dbInfo = array(
    'host'      => "localhost",
    'user'      => "root",
    'pass'      => "password"
);
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Personally I'd json_encode the array (taking into account any escaping etc needed) and bung the entire lot into an appropriately sized text/blob field.

It makes it very easy to store "unstructured" data but a real PITA to search/index on with any grace.

A simple json_decode will "explode" the data back into an array for you.

Answer (score 5):

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($data));
$escaped_values = array_map(array($con, 'real_escape_string'),array_values($data));
$values  = implode("', '", $escaped_values);
return $sql = "INSERT INTO `reservations`($columns) VALUES ('$values')";
```

This is improvement to the solution given by Shiplu Mokaddim

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 ways of doing it:

- You can create a table (or multiple tables linked together) with a field for each key of your array, and insert into each field the corresponding value of your array. This is the most common way
- You can just have a table with one field and put in here your array [serialized](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.serialize.php). I do not recommend you do do that, but it is useful if you don't want a complex database schema.

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table ( " . implode(', ', array_keys($insData)) . ")
    VALUES (" . implode(', ', array_values($insData)) . ")";
```

Only need to write this line to insert an array into a database.

`implode(', ', array_keys($insData))`  : *Gives you all keys as string format*

`implode(', ', array_values($insData))` : *Gives you all values as string format*

Comment: Please be warned that your query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection and should never be used like that, unless you plan to get hacked. Use prepared statements to avoid this

Comment: @NicoHaase now let me know who is rude. If you really want to give solution to help others, you can easily edit this and added fixes.  I don't want you to feel obligated to comment on every one of my posts.

Answer (score 2):

**Insert array data into mysql php**

I Have array data.. I want post that data in database

**1: this is my array data:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [questions] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [question_id] => 54
                    [question] => Which%20of%20the%20following%20is%20a%20rational%20number%20(s)%3F%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cbr%20%2F%3E
                    [option_1] => %3Cimg%20align%3D%22middle%22%20%20%20src%3D%22formula%2F54%2F010779c34ce28fee25778247e127b82d.png%22%20alt%3D%22%22%20%2F%3E%3Cspan%20class%3D%22Apple-tab-span%22%20style%3D%22white-space%3A%20pre%3B%20%22%3E%09%3C%2Fspan%3E
                    [option_2] => %26nbsp%3B%3Cimg%20align%3D%22middle%22%20%20%20src%3D%22formula%2F54%2F3af35a16c371ffaaf9ea6891fb732478.png%22%20alt%3D%22%22%20%2F%3E
                    [option_3] => %26nbsp%3B%3Cimg%20align%3D%22middle%22%20%20%20src%3D%22formula%2F54%2F4a57d5766a79f0ddf659d63c7443982b.png%22%20alt%3D%22%22%20%2F%3E
                    [option_4] => %26nbsp%3BAll%20the%20above%26nbsp%3B
                    [iscorrect] => yes
                    [answerGiven] => D
                    [marksobtain] => 2
                    [timetaken] => 3
                    [difficulty_levelval] => 2
                )


   [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [question_id] => 58
                    [question] => %3Cdiv%3EIf%20A%20%26nbsp%3B%3A%20Every%20whole%20number%20is%20a%20natural%20number%20and%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%3Cdiv%3E%26nbsp%3B%20%26nbsp%3BR%20%3A%200%20is%20not%20a%20natural%20number%2C%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%3Cdiv%3EThen%20which%20of%20the%20following%20statement%20is%20true%3F%3C%2Fdiv%3E
                    [option_1] => %26nbsp%3BA%20is%20False%20and%20R%20is%20true.
                    [option_2] => A%20is%20True%20and%20R%20is%20the%20correct%20explanation%20of%20A
                    [option_3] => %26nbsp%3BA%20is%20True%20and%20R%20is%20false
                    [option_4] => %26nbsp%3BBoth%20A%20and%20R%20are%20True
                    [iscorrect] => no
                    [answerGiven] => D
                    [marksobtain] => 0
                    [timetaken] => 2
                    [difficulty_levelval] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

code used i used to insert that data:

Code ::

```
<?php 
 //require_once("config_new2012.php");

require("codelibrary/fb/facebook.php");
include("codelibrary/inc/variables.php");
include_once(INC."functions.php");
include_once(CLASSES."frontuser_class.php");
include_once(CLASSES."testdetails_class.php");



$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$arr_data = explode("=",$data);
$final_data = urldecode($arr_data[1]);
$final_data2 = json_decode($final_data);


 //print_r ($final_data2);



 if(is_array($final_data2)){
echo 'i am in array ';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO p_user_test_details(question_id, question, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4,iscorrect,answerGiven,marksobtain,timetaken,difficulty_levelval) values ";

    $valuesArr = array();
    foreach($final_data2 as $row){

        $question_id = (int) $row['question_id'];
        $question = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['question'] );
        $option_1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['option_1'] );
    $option_2 = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['option_2'] );
    $option_3 = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['option_3'] );
    $option_4 = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['option_4'] );
    $iscorrect = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['iscorrect'] );
    $answerGiven = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['answerGiven'] );
        $marksobtain = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['marksobtain'] );
        $timetaken = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['timetaken'] );
        $difficulty_levelval = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['difficulty_levelval'] );
        $valuesArr[] = "('$question_id', '$question', '$option_1','$option_2','$option_3','$option_4','$iscorrect','$answerGiven','$marksobtain','$timetaken','$difficulty_levelval')";
    }

    $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

    mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 
}
else{

echo 'no one is there ';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
 function mysqli_insert_array($table, $data, $exclude = array()) {
    $con=  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","test");
     $fields = $values = array();
    if( !is_array($exclude) ) $exclude = array($exclude);
    foreach( array_keys($data) as $key ) {
        if( !in_array($key, $exclude) ) {
            $fields[] = "`$key`";
            $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[$key]) . "'";
        }
    }
    $fields = implode(",", $fields);
    $values = implode(",", $values);
    if( mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `$table` ($fields) VALUES ($values)") ) {
        return array( "mysql_error" => false,
                      "mysql_insert_id" => mysqli_insert_id($con),
                      "mysql_affected_rows" => mysqli_affected_rows($con),
                      "mysql_info" => mysqli_info($con)
                    );
    } else {
        return array( "mysql_error" => mysqli_error($con) );
    }
}

 $a['firstname']="abc";
 $a['last name']="xyz";
 $a['birthdate']="1993-09-12";
 $a['profilepic']="img.jpg";
 $a['gender']="male";
 $a['email']="abc@hightecit.com";
 $a['likechoclate']="Dm";
 $a['status']="1";
$result=mysqli_insert_array('registration',$a,'abc');
if( $result['mysql_error'] ) {
    echo "Query Failed: " . $result['mysql_error'];
} else {
    echo "Query Succeeded! <br />";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string uses now link

Answer (score 1):

[Serialize](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.serialize.php) the array and you'll have a text on your database column, that will solve the problem.

I do that, for instance to save objects, that way I can retrieve them easily.

Comment: **virtual -1**, saving data in a non-normalized table is **bad** practice.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - I agree in the main, but it is not always true. Tables with a small number of custom child columns can get a great speed benefit using this approach - Wordpress uses it.

Comment: It can be beneficial. But you should not use it when you are developing something. You should use this when you got performance problem and the benchmark shows positive result. Not before that. Its premature optimization.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be to complex for this question but it surely do the job for you. I have created two classes to handle not only array insertion but also querying the database, updating and deleting files. "MySqliConnection" class is used to create only one instance of db connection (to prevent duplication of new objects).

```
    <?php
    /**
     *
     * MySQLi database connection: only one connection is allowed
     */
    class MySqliConnection{
        public static $_instance;
        public $_connection;

        public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database){
            $this->_connection = new MySQLi($host, $user, $password, $database);
            if (isset($mysqli->connect_error)) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
                echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
            }
        }

        /*
        * Gets instance of connection to database
        * @return (MySqliConnection) Object
        */
        public static function getInstance($host, $user, $password, $database){
            if(!self::$_instance){ 
                self::$_instance = new self($host, $user, $password, $database); //if no instance were created - new one will be initialize
            }
            return self::$_instance; //return already exsiting instance of the database connection
        }

        /*
        * Prevent database connection from bing copied while assignig the object to new wariable
        * @return (MySqliConnection) Object
        */
        public function getConnection(){
            return $this->_connection;
        }

        /*
        * Prevent database connection from bing copied/duplicated while assignig the object to new wariable
        * @return nothing
        */
        function __clone(){

        }
    }


    /*// CLASS USE EXAMPLE 
        $db = MySqliConnection::getInstance('localhost', 'root', '', 'sandbox');
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();
        $sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM users;
            $this->lastQuery = $sql_query;
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            echo $row['ID'];
        }

    */
```

The second "TableManager" class is little bit more complex. It also make use of the MySqliConnection class which I posted above. So you would have to include both of them in your project. TableManager will allow you to easy make insertion updates and deletions. Class have separate placeholder for read and write.

```
<?php

/*
* DEPENDENCIES:
* include 'class.MySqliConnection.inc'; //custom class
*
*/

class TableManager{

    private $lastQuery;
    private $lastInsertId;
    private $tableName;
    private $tableIdName;
    private $columnNames = array();
    private $lastResult = array();
    private $curentRow = array();
    private $newPost = array();

    /*
    * Class constructor 
    * [1] (string) $tableName // name of the table which you want to work with
    * [2] (string) $tableIdName // name of the ID field which will be used to delete and update records
    * @return void
    */
    function __construct($tableName, $tableIdName){
        $this->tableIdName = $tableIdName;
        $this->tableName = $tableName;
        $this->getColumnNames();
        $this->curentRow = $this->columnNames;
    }

public function getColumnNames(){
    $sql_query = 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = "'.$this->tableName.'"';
    $mysqli = $this->connection();
    $this->lastQuery = $sql_query;
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception("Database Error [{$this->database->errno}] {$this->database->error}");
    }
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){           
        $this->columnNames[$row['COLUMN_NAME']] = null;
    }
}

    /*
    * Used by a Constructor to set native parameters or virtual array curentRow of the class
    * [1] (array) $v
    * @return void
    */
    function setRowValues($v){

        if(!is_array($v)){
            $this->curentRow = $v;
            return true;    
        }
        foreach ($v as $a => $b) {
            $method = 'set'.ucfirst($a);
            if(is_callable(array($this, $method))){
                //if method is callable use setSomeFunction($k, $v) to filter the value
                $this->$method($b);
            }else{
                $this->curentRow[$a] = $b;
            }
        }

    }

    /*
    * Used by a constructor to set native parameters or virtual array curentRow of the class
    * [0]
    * @return void
    */
    function __toString(){
        var_dump($this);
    }

    /*
    * Query Database for information - Select column in table where column = somevalue
    * [1] (string) $column_name // name od a column
    * [2] (string) $quote_pos // searched value in a specified column
    * @return void
    */
    public function getRow($column_name = false, $quote_post = false){
        $mysqli = $this->connection();
        $quote_post = $mysqli->real_escape_string($quote_post);
        $this->tableName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($this->tableName);
        $column_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($column_name);
        if($this->tableName && $column_name && $quote_post){
            $sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$this->tableName.' WHERE '.$column_name.' = "'.$quote_post.'"';
            $this->lastQuery = $sql_query;
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
            if (!$result) {
                throw new Exception("Database Error [{$this->database->errno}] {$this->database->error}");
            }
            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $this->lastResult[$row['ID']] = $row;
                $this->setRowValues($row);
            }
        }
        if($this->tableName && $column_name && !$quote_post){
            $sql_query = 'SELECT '.$column_name.' FROM '.$this->tableName.'';
            $this->lastQuery = $sql_query;
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
            if (!$result) {
                throw new Exception("Database Error [{$this->database->errno}] {$this->database->error}");
            }
            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){           
                $this->lastResult[] = $row;
                $this->setRowValues($row);
            }       
        }
        if($this->tableName && !$column_name && !$quote_post){
            $sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$this->tableName.'';
            $this->lastQuery = $sql_query;
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
            if (!$result) {
                throw new Exception("Database Error [{$this->database->errno}] {$this->database->error}");
            }
            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){           
                $this->lastResult[$row['ID']] = $row;
                $this->setRowValues($row);
            }       
        }
    }


    /*
    * Connection class gets instance of db connection or if not exsist creats one
    * [0]
    * @return $mysqli
    */
    private function connection(){
        $this->lastResult = "";
        $db = MySqliConnection::getInstance('localhost', 'root', '', 'sandbox');
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();
        return $mysqli;
    }

    /*
    * ...
    * [1] (string) $getMe
    * @return void
    */
    function __get($getMe){
        if(isset($this->curentRow[$getMe])){
            return $this->curentRow[$getMe];
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Error Processing Request - No such a property in (array) $this->curentRow", 1);
        }

    }

    /*
    * ...
    * [2] (string) $setMe, (string) $value
    * @return void
    */
    function __set($setMe, $value){
        $temp = array($setMe=>$value);
        $this->setRowValues($temp);
    }

    /*
    * Dumps the object
    * [0] 
    * @return void
    */
    function dump(){
        echo "<hr>";
        var_dump($this);
        echo "<hr>";
    }

    /*
    * Sets Values for $this->newPost array which will be than inserted by insertNewPost() function
    * [1] (array) $newPost //array of avlue that will be inserted to $this->newPost
    * @return bolean
    */
    public function setNewRow($arr){

        if(!is_array($arr)){
            $this->newPost = $arr;
            return false;   
        }
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            if(array_key_exists($k, $this->columnNames)){
                $method = 'set'.ucfirst($k);
                if(is_callable(array($this, $method))){
                    if($this->$method($v) == false){ //if something go wrong
                        $this->newPost = array(); //empty the newPost array and return flase
                        throw new Exception("There was a problem in setting up New Post parameters. [Cleaning array]", 1);
                    }
                }else{
                    $this->newPost[$k] = $v;
                }
            }else{
                $this->newPost = array(); //empty the newPost array and return flase
                throw new Exception("The column does not exsist in this table. [Cleaning array]", 1);
            }
        }

    }


    /*
    * Inserts new post held in $this->newPost
    * [0]
    * @return bolean
    */
    public function insertNewRow(){
        // check if is set, is array and is not null
        if(isset($this->newPost) && !is_null($this->newPost) && is_array($this->newPost)){
            $mysqli = $this->connection();
            $count_lenght_of_array = count($this->newPost);

            // preper insert query
            $sql_query = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->tableName.' (';
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($this->newPost as $key => $value) {
                $sql_query .=$key;
                if ($i < $count_lenght_of_array) {
                    $sql_query .=', ';
                }

                $i++;
             } 

            $i = 1;  
            $sql_query .=') VALUES (';
            foreach ($this->newPost as $key => $value) {
                $sql_query .='"'.$value.'"';
                if ($i < $count_lenght_of_array) {
                    $sql_query .=', ';
                }

                $i++;
             }  

            $sql_query .=')';
            var_dump($sql_query);
            if($mysqli->query($sql_query)){
                $this->lastInsertId = $mysqli->insert_id;
                $this->lastQuery = $sql_query;
            }

            $this->getInsertedPost($this->lastInsertId);
        }
    }   

    /*
    * getInsertedPost function query the last inserted id and assigned it to the object.
    * [1] (integer) $id // last inserted id from insertNewRow fucntion
    * @return void
    */
    private function getInsertedPost($id){
        $mysqli = $this->connection();
        $sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$this->tableName.' WHERE '.$this->tableIdName.' = "'.$id.'"';
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $this->lastResult[$row['ID']] = $row;
            $this->setRowValues($row);
        }       
    }

    /*
    * getInsertedPost function query the last inserted id and assigned it to the object.
    * [0]
    * @return bolean // if deletion was successful return true
    */
    public function deleteLastInsertedPost(){
        $mysqli = $this->connection();
        $sql_query = 'DELETE FROM '.$this->tableName.' WHERE '.$this->tableIdName.' = '.$this->lastInsertId.'';
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
        if($result){
            $this->lastResult[$this->lastInsertId] = "deleted";
            return true;
        }else{
            throw new Exception("We could not delete last inserted row by ID [{$mysqli->errno}] {$mysqli->error}");

        }
        var_dump($sql_query);       
    }

    /*
    * deleteRow function delete the row with from a table based on a passed id
    * [1] (integer) $id // id of the table row to be delated
    * @return bolean // if deletion was successful return true
    */
    public function deleteRow($id){
        $mysqli = $this->connection();
        $sql_query = 'DELETE FROM '.$this->tableName.' WHERE '.$this->tableIdName.' = '.$id.'';
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
        if($result){
            $this->lastResult[$this->lastInsertId] = "deleted";
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        var_dump($sql_query);       
    }

    /*
    * deleteAllRows function deletes all rows from a table
    * [0]
    * @return bolean // if deletion was successful return true
    */
    public function deleteAllRows(){
        $mysqli = $this->connection();
        $sql_query = 'DELETE FROM '.$this->tableName.'';
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
        if($result){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }       
    }

    /*
    * updateRow function updates all values to object values in a row with id
    * [1] (integer) $id
    * @return bolean // if deletion was successful return true
    */
    public function updateRow($update_where = false){
        $id = $this->curentRow[$this->tableIdName];
        $mysqli = $this->connection();
        $updateMe = $this->curentRow;
        unset($updateMe[$this->tableIdName]);
        $count_lenght_of_array = count($updateMe);
        // preper insert query
        $sql_query = 'UPDATE '.$this->tableName.' SET ';
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($updateMe as $k => $v) {
            $sql_query .= $k.' = "'.$v.'"';
            if ($i < $count_lenght_of_array) {
                $sql_query .=', ';
            }

            $i++;
         }
        if($update_where == false){ 
            //update row only for this object id
            $sql_query .=' WHERE '.$this->tableIdName.' = '.$this->curentRow[$this->tableIdName].'';
        }else{
            //add your custom update where query
            $sql_query .=' WHERE '.$update_where.'';
        }

        var_dump($sql_query);
        if($mysqli->query($sql_query)){
            $this->lastQuery = $sql_query;
        }
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
        if($result){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }       
    }

}



/*TO DO

1 insertPost(X, X) write function to isert data and in to database;
2 get better query system and display data from database;
3 write function that displays data of a object not databsae;
object should be precise and alocate only one instance of the post at a time. 
// Updating the Posts to curent object $this->curentRow values
->updatePost();

// Deleting the curent post by ID

// Add new row to database

*/





/*
USE EXAMPLE
$Post = new TableManager("post_table", "ID"); // New Object

// Getting posts from the database based on pased in paramerters
$Post->getRow('post_name', 'SOME POST TITLE WHICH IS IN DATABASE' );
$Post->getRow('post_name');
$Post->getRow();



MAGIC GET will read current object  $this->curentRow parameter values by refering to its key as in a varible name
echo $Post->ID.
echo $Post->post_name;
echo $Post->post_description;
echo $Post->post_author;


$Task = new TableManager("table_name", "table_ID_name"); // creating new TableManager object

$addTask = array( //just an array [colum_name] => [values]
    'task_name' => 'New Post',
    'description' => 'New Description Post',
    'person' => 'New Author',
    );
$Task->setNewRow($addTask); //preper new values for insertion to table
$Task->getRow('ID', '12'); //load value from table to object

$Task->insertNewRow(); //inserts new row
$Task->dump(); //diplays object properities

$Task->person = "John"; //magic __set() method will look for setPerson(x,y) method firs if non found will assign value as it is. 
$Task->description = "John Doe is a funny guy"; //magic __set() again
$Task->task_name = "John chellange"; //magic __set() again

$test = ($Task->updateRow("ID = 5")) ? "WORKS FINE" : "ERROR"; //update cutom row with object values
echo $test;
$test = ($Task->updateRow()) ? "WORKS FINE" : "ERROR"; //update curent data loaded in object
echo $test;
*/
```

Comment: at first look 1) unreachable statements (var_dump) 2) to string doesn't return string 3)  mixed return when void expected (use same return not return true) 4) redundant/not allowed usage of ' 5) connection constructor has mixed instance /mysqli undefined var usage 6) typos

Comment: Please be warned that your query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection and should never be used like that, unless you plan to get hacked. Use prepared statements to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

most easiest way

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($tableData); $i++) { 

        $cost     =$tableData[$i]['cost'];
        $quantity =$tableData[$i]['quantity'];
        $price    =$tableData[$i]['price'];
        $p_id     =$tableData[$i]['p_id'];

        mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO bill_details (bill_id, price, bill_date, p_id, quantity, cost) VALUES ($bill_id[bill_id],$price,$date,$p_id,$quantity,$cost)");
    }
```

Comment: Please be warned that your query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection and should never be used like that, unless you plan to get hacked. Use prepared statements to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method to escape and insert:

```
global $connection;
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($array_data));
$func = function($value) {
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $value);
};
$escaped_values = array_map($func, array_values($array_data));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO $table_name ($columns) VALUES ($values)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's not forget the most important thing to learn out of a question like this: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Click [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for a tutorial on PDO.

Answer (score 0):

```
function insertQuery($tableName,$cols,$values,$connection){
  $numberOfColsAndValues = count($cols);
  $query = 'INSERT INTO '.$tableName.' ('.getColNames($cols,$numberOfColsAndValues).') VALUES ('.getColValues($values,$numberOfColsAndValues).')';
   if(mysqli_query($connection, $query))
      return true;
   else{
      echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
      return false;
   }
}

function getColNames($cols,$numberOfColsAndValues){
  $result = '';
  foreach($cols as $key => $val){
    $result = $result.$val.', ';
  }
    return substr($result,0,strlen($result)-2);
}


function getColValues($values,$numberOfColsAndValues){
  $result = '';
  foreach($values as $key => $val){
    $val = "'$val'";
    $result = $result.$val.', ';
  }
    return substr($result,0,strlen($result)-2);
}
```

Comment: Please be warned that your query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection and should never be used like that, unless you plan to get hacked. Use prepared statements to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

This based on answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054657/7404511]

Here is a standard MySQL insert statement.

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ....) VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE2..)
```

If you have a table with name fbdata with the columns which are presented in the keys of your array you can insert with this small snippet.
Here is how your array is converted to this statement.

I'd use this solution where explicitly add quotes `'string'` and explicily put `null` for null value:

```php
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($insData));
$escaped_values = array_map(
    function($value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            return "'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($value) . "'";
        }
        if (is_null($value)) {
            return 'null';
        }
        return $value;
    },
    array_values($insData)
);
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `fbdata`($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31161155)

Answer (score -1):

Recently,I'm learning Wordpress,it provide a class WP_QUERY to operate the database. You can insert array or object to the database.I feel it is amazing,so I go to see how to achieve it.Maybe,some ideas you can get from it.The main function is: [apply_filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters).

```
apply_filters( $tag, $value, $key);
```

you can ignore the first parameter ,treat the second parameter as array,what the  function do is sanitizing the array into string.

after inserting into the database,you can see this :

```
key     s:12:"focal_length";s:3:"190";s:3:"iso";s:3:"400";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:6:"0.0004";s:5:"title";s:0:"";}}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't insert anything into the database. Please don't assume that everybody uses Wordpress

Answer (score -1):

I think the simple method would be using

```
ob_start(); //Start output buffer
print_r($var);
$var = ob_get_contents(); //Grab output
ob_end_clean(); //Discard output buffer
```

and your array output will be recorded as a simple variable

Comment: How does this insert the data into the database? As it stands, it doesn't look like this is answering the question.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

You guys can try this, I used this kind of script in my system

```
foreach ($insData as $insData) {
    $insdate = array();

    foreach ($insData as $insData) {
        array_push($arr, $dbname);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblname (uid, first_name, last_name,email,link)
        VALUES ('$uid', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$link')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Successfully insert into db";
    } else {
        echo "Please try again" . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid "try this" answers. It implies that you are unsure whether your solution is correct and that the asker should just "try this" and see if it works. Instead, add an explanation of why what you did works. You step into the role of teacher when answering, so be the best teacher you can!

Comment: Please be warned that your query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection and should never be used like that, unless you plan to get hacked. Use prepared statements to avoid this

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id[]" value="<?php echo $value->item_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_id[]" value="<?php echo $value->cart_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_price[]" value="<?php echo $TotalItemValue; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="order_id[]" value="<?php echo $value->cart_order_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="commision[]" value="<?php echo number_format($commissionamount); ?>">
</html>

$myarray = array();

foreach ($this->input->post('item_id') as $key => $val) {
    $myarray = [
        'item_id' => $val,
        'order_id' => $order_id[$key],
        'recon_gt_amount' => $recon_gt_amount[$key],
        'recon_gt_commision' => $recon_gt_commision[$key],
        'recon_gt_payment' => $recon_gt_payment[$key],
        'cart_id' => $cart_id[$key],
    ] ;

    $result['save_recon_finance'] = $this->productmodel->recondata_financeinsert($myarray);
}
```

Comment: Where does `recondata_financeinsert` come from? The original code does not contain that function

Answer (score -1):

**We can Do it using serialized() method**

> $serialized_userdata = serialize($data);
> $sql = "insert into $tableName (details) value ('$serialized_userdata')";
> $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please be warned that your query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection and should never be used like that, unless you plan to get hacked. Use prepared statements to avoid this

Answer (score -2):

```
                                    $count = count($data);

                                    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){ 
                                        $name = $data[$i]['name'];
                                        $web_id = $data[$i]['web_id'];
                                        $status = $data[$i]['status'];
                                        $sql = "INSERT INTO pws_xdata_chiefcomplain(name, web_id,status) VALUES (:name,:web_id,:status)";
                                        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
                                        $result= $stmt->execute([
                                                'name' =>$name,
                                                'web_id' =>$web_id,
                                                'status' =>$status,
                                        ]);
                                         
                                      }
```

Comment: This poorly formatted post is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: I edited for readable but u edited too. And cant see half of code ty