# Reverse mysql_fetch_assoc (mysql_set_assoc/mysql_encode_assoc)

Tags: php, mysql

Is there function encoding an associative array to use in a mySQL `INSERT` command?

This way you could do:

```
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$array['key'] = 'updated_value';
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table ' . mysql_encode_assoc($array));
```

mysql_encode_assoc input:

```
array(
    'name' => 'bob',
    'vehicle' => 'car'
)
```

mysql_encode_assoc output:

```
'(name, vehicle) VALUES(bob, car)'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert array into MySQL database with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054633/insert-array-into-mysql-database-with-php)

Comment: You might wish to look for one that creates a `(name,vehicle) VALUES (?,?)` statement instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now:

```
function mysql_encode_assoc($array) {
    $kenc = Array();
    $venc = Array();
    foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
        $kenc[] = "`".mysql_real_escape_string($k)."`";
        if( $v === null) $venc[] = "NULL";
        else $venc[] = '"'.mysql_real_escape_string($v).'"';
    }
    $keys = "(".implode(",",$kenc).")";
    $vals = "(".implode(",",$venc).")";
    return $keys." VALUES ".$vals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in function that I'm aware of. But you can quite easily make on using **[`array_keys()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)** and **[`array_values()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)**.

Answer (score 0):

No built-in function.

```
$sql = array();
foreach ($anArray as $f=>$v) $sql[] = "`{$f}`" = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($v)."'";
$query = "INSERT INTO table SET ".join(",", $sql);
```