# How to insert multiple rows in to mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I've got an array called `$changedcompanies` and I want to insert the contents into my mySQL table.

Currently I'm using a for loop in php which must be an inefficent way of going about it:

```
for ($x=0;$x<count($changedcompanies);$x++){
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ecampaign_historyamend SET historyid = '".$lastid."', 
        companyid = '".$changedcompanies[$x]['id']."', 
        newcontactid = '".$changedcompanies[$x]['contactid']."'";
        $s   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Error inserting history amend: ' . $e->getMessage();
        showerror($error);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to design a mySQL query that will insert the whole array in one go?

Comment: You're using prepared statements incorrectly. You need to use placeholders instead of adding the variables each time - prepare the statement outside the for loop, and just execute it inside the loop, passing the different variables each time.

Comment: I think this is already explained here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054633/insert-array-into-mysql-database-with-php

Comment: See color's mismatch in highlightning? You have syntax errors!

Comment: @IndraKumarS - it's an alternative version of the INSERT syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert.html

Comment: @IndraKumarS, this is perfectly correct

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: How did you conclude this is inefficient?Premature optimization is the root of all evil..

Comment: Those prepared statements are funny.

Answer (score 1):

Connect them all, then run them. Do not forget the semicolon between commands:

```
$sql="";
for ($x=0;$x<count($changedcompanies);$x++){
        $sql.= "INSERT INTO ecampaign_historyamend SET historyid = '".$lastid."', 
        companyid = '".$changedcompanies[$x]['id']."', 
        newcontactid = '".$changedcompanies[$x]['contactid']."';";
}

try {
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
$error = 'Error inserting history amend: ' . $e->getMessage();
showerror($error);
exit();
}
```