# How To Extract Data From Array And Store To Database

Tags: php, alexa-skills-kit

**EDIT:**

I've decided to totally change how I put this to you guys. I'm using the script provided by Amazon to connect to the Alexa API and get some information. I have a table in my database that I'm pulling rows from (by the URL) and using this script to try to update some columns that are currently blank with this gathered information.

The example below is showing the results I get for http://google.com

I hope I've worded this right and haven't been too confusing.

The following code:

```
public static function parseResponse($response) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response,null,false,
                                'http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11');
    if($xml->count() && $xml->Response->UrlInfoResult->Alexa->count()) {
        $info = $xml->Response->UrlInfoResult->Alexa;
        $nice_array = array(
            'Phone Number'   => $info->ContactInfo->PhoneNumbers->PhoneNumber,
            'Owner Name'     => $info->ContactInfo->OwnerName,
            'Email'          => $info->ContactInfo->Email,
            'Street'         => $info->ContactInfo->PhysicalAddress->Streets->Street,
            'City'           => $info->ContactInfo->PhysicalAddress->City,
            'State'          => $info->ContactInfo->PhysicalAddress->State,
            'Postal Code'    => $info->ContactInfo->PhysicalAddress->PostalCode,
            'Country'        => $info->ContactInfo->PhysicalAddress->Country,
            'Links In Count' => $info->ContentData->LinksInCount,
            'Rank'           => $info->TrafficData->Rank
        );
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(array_values($nice_array));
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Will output this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => unlisted
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => aa
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => dns-admin@google.com
        )

    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => aa
        )

    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => unlisted
        )

    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => unlisted
        )

    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => unlisted
        )

    [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => unlisted
        )

    [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 3555997
        )

    [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
```

As you can see, each of these "objects" correspond to the code above, showing Phone Number, Owner Name, Email, Street, City, State, Postal Code, Country, Links In Count, and Rank, respectively.

What I need to do is take each value and update that row in my database.

Comment: So you want the array's keys or the values of the array?

Comment: I'm thinking I will need each to do what I want. I want to store each value in a separate column within the database. For instance, I have a column for each - "Phone number, owner name, email, street, etc....." I need to extract the values of each of those and store in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert array into MySQL database with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054633/insert-array-into-mysql-database-with-php)

Comment: I've edited my question above. I don't believe it is a duplicate but it could be my (mis)understanding of PHP that leads me to believe this. ;)

Comment: Your question's not an exact duplicate but it's close. Your for loop(that you removed) does the job of the implode on the top answer of that question. You just need a variable that you append the column names to. And another one for the values. Possibly a 3rd if you're using g prepared statements. Don't forget to escape values if not using prepared statements.

Comment: Why dont you show us a query youve tried at this point and we will assist in making it useful.

Comment: I don't have a query to share with you @KirkLogan I haven't written a query because I can't extract the values of the arrays to write a query.

Comment: This is fit for a Google search not a question. Try something. Then we can help.

Comment: @KirkLogan I had searched Google at that point and was not finding anything. Thanks for the tip though! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let PHP do the work for you; [values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) or the [keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: I'm still unable to wrap my mind around how to write a statement to update a row in the database.