# Php, Mysql insert dynamic query

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => John
    [email] => lcook0@mail.co.uk
    [website] => google.com
    [phone] => 0-(343)926-3114
    [address] => 620 Main Center
    [city] => Fukushima-shi
    [country] => JP
    [zip] => 
    [vat] => 123456
    [status] => 1
    [created] => 2016-03-10 15:56:44
)
```

but I will not know the keys and values, since each array will be different. What I need is to insert array into database. Something like:

```
$keys = '';
$values = '';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $keys .= implode(",", $key);
    $values .= implode(",", $value);
}
"INSERT INTO `users` ($keys) VALUES ($values);"
```

My example does not work, since implode requires an array

Comment: First of all above one is not an array.It's an object

Comment: How are you getting that "Object"?

Comment: I can cast an array to (array)$array object

Comment: are you using `mysqli` or `pdo`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert array into MySQL database with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054633/insert-array-into-mysql-database-with-php)

Comment: can you add the DDL of the target table you wanna use? The structure of the array will always be the same, only the content will varry or does even the structure of the array will varry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the alternative insert format: `INSERT INTO tbl SET x=1, y=2...`

This is also a great opportunity for prepared queries:

```
$mapped = array_map(function($k) {return "`".$k."` = ?";},array_keys($array));
$stmt = $dbconnection->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` SET ".implode(", ",$mapped);
$stmt->execute(array_values($array));
```

The exact code, including how to pass the parameter values, will vary but the above is PDO-ish in style. In your example, you'd end up with:

```
INSERT INTO `users` SET `id` = ?, `name` = ? ...
```

And the values `1`, `John` ... would be sent appropriately.

Comment: I think your list line of code is wrong $stmt->execute(array_values($mapped)); it should be $stmt->execute(array_values($array));

Comment: @Alko Indeed, well spotted!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are imploding a string rather than an array. Do it in this manner:

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    $keys[] = "`$key`";
    $values[] = "'$value'";
}

$keys = implode(",", $keys);
$values = implode(",", $values);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` ($keys) VALUES ($values);";
```