# How to insert values in a PHP array to a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I am creating a registration form, with fields for Name, Email and Phone Number. To check the validity of user input, I have a function `validate_input()` that returns an array `$arr` containing input entered by the user (if user input is valid). `$arr` is then passed to a separate function that inserts the values in `arr` into a MySQL table `user` containing fields for `name`, `email` and `phone`.

I initially tried the following:

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, phone)
                 VALUES ('$arr['name']',
                         '$arr['email']',
                         '$arr['phone']')";
$run_insert_query = mysqli_query($con, $insert_query);
```

But this didn't work. Some reading revealed that this is the wrong way to insert array values into the database. So I then tried the following ([based on the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054633/insert-array-into-mysql-database-with-php)):

```
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($arr));
$arr_values  = implode(",", $escaped_values);

$insert_query = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, phone) VALUES ($arr_values)";
$run_query = mysqli_query($con, $insert_query);
```

But this didn't work either. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: both methods are valid, both cases simply have syntax errors

Comment: @rtfm can you please post an answer with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to set the quotes right.
Here's the correct syntax:

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, phone) 
                 VALUES ('".$arr['name']."',
                         '".$arr['email']."', 
                         '".$arr['phone']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your insert dml statement, strings and *formatted* dates must be quoted in single quotes. Since mysql will attempt to dynamically cast strings to integers or floats, you could *try* quoting everything - but even if it you get it working, this will bite you back when you least expect it. Your second block of code is also dependent on the data being presented in the order you expect. Typically this is unlikely to change, but it is bad programming.

You can't mix mysqli_ and mysql_ functions. Read the errors and warnings php is telling you about.

Assuming that your validate_input() function also invokes mysql[i]_real_escape_string() on the data to prevent sql injection (also bad programming practice - you should validate input and escape output) then you just need to fix the semantics of your code in the first query: associative array indices should not be quoted when they are already enclosed in "....":

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO user 
 (name, email, phone)  
 VALUES ('$arr[name]', '$arr[email]', '$arr[phone]')";
$run_insert_query = mysqli_query($con, $insert_query);
```

Comment: much better to still use quotes for array keys

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php read the section "Array do's and don'ts ¶"

Comment: @symcbean Thanks. Can you please explain what you mean by "escape output" in your answer? If I ask any noob questions, please bear with me - I'm quite new to web dev.

Comment: @rtfm: I have read it - I suggest you take the time to read it too. And to understand what it is telling you.

Comment: **Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example, $foo['bar'] is correct, while $foo[bar] is not.** could it be more explicit?

Comment: @rtfm: keep reading: `echo "Bad: {$array['$i']}\n"; echo "Good: {$array[$i]}\n";`