# Php array to column row in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have array named olmali

```
$olmali = $_POST['result'];
```

and `print_r($olmali);` 
Result is below :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 20
    [3] => 2 
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6 
    [7] => 7 
    [8] => 9 
    [9] => 8 
    [10] => 10
    [11] => 11
    [12] => 13
    [13] => 12 
    [14] => 12
    [15] => 14 
    [16] => 15
    [17] => 16
    [18] => 17
    [19] => 17
    [20] => 19
    [21] => 20
)
```

Result are going to test column in SQL table in phpmyadmin like :

```
id        test
1         array
```

But I expect :

```
id        test
1          1
2          1
3          20
4          2
5          3
6         ....and goes on
```

How can I resolve this problem ? İs there any way and how can I do it. PHP array to column row in MySQL table like that

Comment: `Result are going to test column in SQL table` - where is your  code?

Comment: Do further reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054633/insert-array-into-mysql-database-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through the array and insert one by one.

```
foreach($olmali as $v)
{
    //insert query goes here
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name (test) VALUES ('$v')";

   // Then Execute the query 
}
```

Another approach is to use `Bulk Insert`,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name (test) VALUES ";   

foreach($olmali as $v)
{
    //Concatenate values in bulk
    $sql .= "('$v'),";
}

$sql = rtrim($sql, ','); // Remove extra comma at the end
// Then execute query
```

Comment: Concatting the query like @suresh is doing is more cost efficient

Comment: Yes, it can be done using bulk insert. Making the OP understand basics first  :). Added bulk insert example in my answer too.

Comment: Nice. Good answer!

Comment: thanks very much for your solution . Bulk insert is working perfect

Comment: Please elaborate on it.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways
*1:using Bulk insert*

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO tableName(test) VALUES ";
    foreach($olmali as $val){
       $qry .="($val),";
    }

    $qry = preg_replace("/\,$/", ";", $qry);

    $conn->query($sql);
```

*2:using prepare statement*  preferred way

```
$stmt =  $db->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName(test) VALUES(?)");
foreach($olmali as $val)
{
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$val);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: how can ı do this with sql update command ? not insert command

Comment: $stmt =  $db->stmt_init(); $stmt->prepare("UPDATE tableName SET test=? WHERE id=?"); foreach($olmali as $key=>$val)
{
    $stmt->bind_param('ii',$val,$key);
    $stmt->execute();
}